# Hive Query to insert a value conditionally

Tags: sql, hive, case, hiveql

I have a `Table1` containing some blacklisted names. Now suppose I receive a record `"def"`. The hive query should check if `"def"` is present in `Table1` or not. If not the `name_status` should be set to `blacklisted` otherwise `null`. The name `"def"` will be inserted in both cases. The problem I am facing is that in hive we cannot use subquery in `from` clause only.

Table1

```
----blacklisted_names------

         "abc"

         "xyz"

---------------------------
```

Table 2 (before receiveing `"def"`)

```
---name--|--name_status-----
         |
"abc"    |   blacklisted
         |
         |
----------------------------
```

Table 2 (after receiveing `"def"`)

```
---name--|--name_status-----
         |
"abc"    |   blacklisted
         |
"def"    |    null
----------------------------
```

Table 2 (after receiveing `"xyz"`)

```
---name--|--name_status-----
         |
"abc"    |   blacklisted
         |
"def"    |    null
         |
"xyz"    |   blaclisted
----------------------------
```

Comment: How are you inserting and receiving rows

Comment: @leftjoin from another table

Comment: Then use template like in my answer. new_rows is another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with blacklist and use CASE to assign 'blaclisted' for joined rows

```
insert into table2
select n.name,
       case when b.name is not null then 'blacklisted' end as name_status
 from new_rows n
      left join table1 b --blacklisted
                on n.name=b.name
```